# iOS: Cannot use Activity Indicator inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to have `ActivityIndicatorView` inside each `UITableViewCell` and start animation after tap (to show that action is in progress). But I cannot start the animation effect.

I added `ActivityIndicatorView` to my cell prototype and connected it via `@IBOutlet`. This is my code to start animation after user selects table row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let selectedAction = actions[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "actionCell", for: indexPath) as! ActionTableViewCell

        cell.activityInProgressIndicator.startAnimating()

    }
```

I also tried adding new instance of `ActivityIndicatorView` as cell.accessoryView. Without any effect.

I also tried to update the cell either via `tableView.reloadData()` (which I would like to avoid) and `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`

Ideally this spinning indicator should be hidden but setting `.isHidden = false` in `didSelectRowAt` also does not work.

Comment: can you see the indicator there? is the problem just to start it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ yes, if I don't set isHidden to true then the indicator is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating new instance of `ActionTableViewCell` when you use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` inside `didSelectRowAt`, which is wrong.
You need to use something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ActionTableViewCell else { return }
    cell.activityInProgressIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "actionCell",
 for: indexPath) as! ActionTableViewCell with below line

 let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ActionTableViewCell.
```

Hope it will work!!